# linux file recovery utility for corrupted Truecrypt NTFS disk

Tags: linux, ntfs, truecrypt

I have a true-crypt disk (the whole device is encrypted) with bad sectors.  I can mount the volume on Ubuntu machine but every utility I try freezes while trying to copy files of it.

Is there some utility I can use to save as many files as I can?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can try foremost() from Ubuntu, while the device is mounted.

Comment: how do i do it ?

Comment: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/DataRecovery https://help.ubuntu.com/community/DataRecovery#Foremost

Answer (score 2):

Whatever backups you made are your best chance.  **You did make backups, right?**

According to the [Truecrypt FAQ](http://www.truecrypt.org/faq), your best bet is to use Windows filesystem-repair tools (`chkdsk`, or 3rd-party tools):

> **What will happen when a part of a
>   TrueCrypt volume becomes corrupted?**
>
> In encrypted data, one corrupted bit
>   usually corrupts the whole ciphertext
>   block in which it occurred. The
>   ciphertext block size used by
>   TrueCrypt is 16 bytes (i.e., 128
>   bits). The mode of operation used by
>   TrueCrypt ensures that if data
>   corruption occurs within a block, the
>   remaining blocks are not affected. See
>   also the question 'What do I do when
>   the encrypted filesystem on my
>   TrueCrypt volume is corrupted?
>
> **What do I do when the encrypted
>   filesystem on my TrueCrypt volume is
>   corrupted?**
>
> File system within a TrueCrypt volume
>   may become corrupted in the same way
>   as any normal unencrypted file system.
>   When that happens, you can use
>   filesystem repair tools supplied with
>   your operating system to fix it. In
>   Windows, it is the 'chkdsk' tool.
>   TrueCrypt provides an easy way to use
>   this tool on a TrueCrypt volume:
>   Right-click the mounted volume in the
>   main TrueCrypt window (in the drive
>   list) and from the context menu select
>   'Repair Filesystem'.

Answer (score 1):

The various versions of ddrescue or dd_rescue can repeatedly try to read an unreadable block but also skip the unreadable blocks and come back to them later after reading what it can in the first pass.